# OAuth v2 Issues with Microsoft Account connection

Tags: oauth, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5, microsoft-account

I have been trying to implement the OAuth v2 for Microsoft Accounts for my website. Its currently in development stage and so am testing on localhost. The Website is an ASP.NET Core MVC 5 Application.

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) to implement OAuth for Twitter, Google and Facebook accounts. I found this to be quite simple with only a few small issues that I was able to solve with simple google searches.

However I have spent several days trying to understand what is happening when trying to use Microsoft Account authentication on my site.

I have watched the video [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview) on registering an application in the Microsoft App Registration Portal. At around minute 6 in the video a short demo shows how to set up the App. You can see my App details in the following screen shot:

[image]

In the video at about 7.5 mins in, there is a small section explaining how to test the App by building a URL string.

On submitting the query string to the browser the page is redirected as expected to my App page as you can see here:

[image: Microsoft Account Sign In Page]

In this instance I was all ready signed into my Microsoft Outlook account. If I wasn't signed in I would be prompted to login to a Microsoft account. Logging in, in this case choosing my already signed in Outlook account causes the page to be redirected back to my site as seen in the following screen shot but because the site didn't send the request its not expecting a token sent back for login so nothing really happens. This is expected behaviour, at this point as I was only testing that the Apps end point was working as expected.

[[image: Redirected Back To Site[5]]

The next stage is to test the functionality from my website. This is where I always have issues. To activate the OAuth functionality for Microsoft Account login requires simply un-commenting a couple of lines of code within the Startup.Auth.cs file in my websites App_Start folder and passing in the Apps ClientKey and ClientSecret values as can bee seen in the following code snippet:

```
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            clientId: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftOAuthClientID"],
            clientSecret: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftOAuthClientSecret"]);
```

This code basically adds a little button to the login page that allows you to choose Microsoft login as can be seen here:

[[image: Microdoft Account Login Button[6]]

When I click the Microsoft button I get the following error page:

[image: Error Page]

And the query string returned contains the following:

> https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=2057#error=unauthorized_client&error_description=The+client+does+not+exist.+If+you+are+the+application+developer%2c+configure+a+new+application+through+the+application+management+site+at+https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.&state=JMxMRuKaOiYWCQw_Uqkhv3gLQn3ULlkG2miM4ymcHhTK5niXVQl5n4L0a6VoWeEKmFM7T1ciU2oQAh26_Y0i2DMjdt6BOAtpjNeMaSpBq4wbCjva9lOuctOUIWwoFdTEGvxJ4M904lUsoudd9e9cYi6eiH3JF81HB5ouQSus2ddE1sVUQLw-YB1GjUL79y2muFaBFIOIOk75oCV2IxX4cFO2rJU04K9Se6gxu698WpzR8taUB2c6tK9u0dBisckhavf0IvKB9dWQq-IVwQgvaA

Anybody know why or what is happening????

Now I have read in several of my many searches while trying to understand whats happening when I try to test the App from my site rather than a URL directly in the browser that I should have

> /signin-microsoft

appended to my Redirect URL in the App Portals configuration. I have Tested with my Redirect URL set like that and this does not work. I get a HTTP ERROR 500 sent back because the page signin-microsoft does not exist. So this is not my problem.

Please help if anyone has had the same issues and solved it.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I was initially trying this using Local IISExpress but after reading some posts saying it can be done only on IIS so I published my site locally to IIS.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full request from login.microsoftonline.com?

Comment: Hi Sorry for delay getting back here I have been so busy with other projects. I'm not sure I understand what you mean @DanielDobalian?

Comment: Can you open a private browsing window, select the "Microsoft" button, then post the auth request to AzureAD.